# Why am I getting 'Open method of Workbooks class failed' error when trying to open Excel file using pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

So, I am using openpyxl and pandas to open an excel file, and write in data. Then, I'm attempting to use pywin32 to open the same file and run a macro to parse the data. But, I'm getting this error when attempting to open the file with pywin32:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

This is the code I'm using with pywin32:

```
    if os.path.exists(self.excel_parser_location):
        # print "Opening Telematics_Messages_Parser.xlsm in Excel"
        xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Application.visible = True
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(self.excel_parser_location), ReadOnly=1)
```

And this is the code I'm using to write in the data before using pywin32:

```
    if os.path.exists(csv_path):
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, error_bad_lines=False)
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.excel_parser_location, keep_vba=True)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.excel_parser_location)
        writer.book = book
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2 RawData', index=False)
        # print 'Writing new data'
        book.remove(book['2 RawData'])
        # print 'Removing blank sheet'
        book_sheet = book['2 RawData1']
        book_sheet.title = '2 RawData'
        # print 'Renaming sheet'
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

I've had a similar issue in the past that I resolved by using an older version of pywin32, but that isn't working now. I'm using pywin32 version 223.

Comment: Maybe try `ReadOnly = True`. That parameter is a variant, and perhaps Excel is expecting a type of VT_BOOL, rather than VT_I4?

Comment: Also `xl.Visible=True` (the Application is redundant) but I doubt that is causing the issue.

Comment: I tried both, but I'm still getting the issue. Although, now it looks like there is a little something extra in the response.

Comment: File "C:\BCP_Telematics_HIL_Test\Mini-Hex-Telematics\Test Scripts\Support_files\Functions\telematics2.py", line 96, in run_parsing_macro
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(self.excel_parser_location), ReadOnly=True)
  File "C:\Users\martita3\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)

Comment: The first 'File' error is where I've been having problems. But, the second 'File' error seems to be new, and I have no idea where its coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occured when path to file is too long. So you should try this code with file with shorter path

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script and see if it works:

```
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(self.excel_parser_location), ReadOnly=1, CorruptLoad=1)
```